# How to submit a form in an iframe and redirect to a page without frames

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

My page contains an iframe. Inside this frame, the user can submit a form. How can I display the submitted form in the whole window, instead of the frame?

Comment: There is an okay question in here but it needs more detail.

Comment: The question has been answered below and the solution works fine. The submit result (after a redirect) is shown in full browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've interpreted your question as:

> My page contains an iframe. Inside this frame, the user can submit a form. How can I display the submitted form in the whole window, instead of the frame?

**Answer**: Set `target="_top"` in your form element:

```
<form target="_top" ...>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think we'll go with your version of the question :)